# How can I create a flow to change a content type after an item is created or modified, without giving people the ability to change the content types?

Tags: content-type, flow

So I have a flow in place where an item's content type changes from "Item" to "Edit item".  The plan here is when someone submits a new item in the list, the next time someone goes to edit that item the form will look different with different fields.  The flow works if I keep "Allow Management of content types" on yes.  However, this also leaves the content type on the form where people can change the content type to whatever they want.  If I turn off the management of content types, my flow no longer works and my items remain the "Item" content type.  How can I change the form from a new entry to an edit entry without letting any user change what content type it is?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will work but try this:

Enable content types on your list. Add your content types. Write your Flow. Then disable content types on the list.

The content types will exist, users won't be able to use them (other than the default) and they'll still be settable via code. At least that's my theory based on years of SharePoint hacking.

Comment: I assumed that would work.  The flow doesn't work when I disable content types.  It works while the content types are enabled, but when I disable them the flow can't see the Content Name I am using.